# How can i used constructor in "Ui\Component\Listing\Column" File In Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, grid

in need to add state columns and get state name from region id so i used object manager for it but that not right way i convert that in constructor method the data of state comes but the column of grid was hide.
[image]

how can i add constructor method in this ??

```
<?php

namespace vendor\mpdule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;


class State extends Column
{
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {   

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $countryFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory')->create();      
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {

                $regionId = $items['state'];
                $region = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Region')
                        ->load($regionId);


                
                $items['state'] = $region['name'];           
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update you code with below code.

```
<?php

namespace vendor\mpdule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Directory\Model\Region;


class State extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var Region
     */
    protected $region;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param Region $region
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Region $region,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
    ) {
        $this->region = $region;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {

                $regionId = $items['state'];
                $region = $this->region->load($regionId);
                
                $items['state'] = $region['name'];           
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> Note: I removed `"$countryFactory"` because it don't used anywhere in
> your code. if you need to use it please define same as like
> `"Region"`.